# Kendo UI validation for Root

Tags: kendo-ui

I have to validate a textbox(for root) in which the string should be started with "/" but should not be ended with "/".
I have gone through regular expression for that but couldn't get any perfect solution.

I have used following code to define rule for that.

```
var validatorRules = {
        rules: {
            customRule1: function (input) {
                var chars = [];
                if (input != "") {
                    chars = input.split('');
                    if (chars[0]!="/" && chars[input.lenght-1]=="/") {
                        return true;
                    }
                }


            }
        },
        messages: {
            customRule1: "Provide proper root"
        }
    };
```

Comment: Can you show what have you tried for this?